# What's the difference between Block helper and Partials in Handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have started looking into Handlebars.js but I am not clear on the difference between Block Helper and Partials in Handlebars.js.

When to use block helper or partials.

https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partial includes one template into another. Block helpers apply logic (I.E. decisions and loops) around the contained block of code.